# Getting potential memory errors I guess - "double free or corruption"

Tags: c++11

I get the error only with negative numbers while it works for all positive numbers. Not really sure what is wrong here. Any help/guidance much appreciated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int insertionSort(std::vector<int> &array){
    // Count the number of shifts needed to sort the array
    int shifts = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++){
        if(array[i] < array[i - 1]){
            int j = i;
            while(array[i] < array[i - 1] && i >= 0){
                shifts++;
                std::swap(array[i], array[i - 1]);
                i--;
            }
            i = j;
        }
    }
    return shifts;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> array = {-1, -2}; // This won't work
    //std::vector<int> array = {1, 2}; // This works
    int shifts = insertionSort(array);
    std::cout << shifts;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You don't ever want `i` to be zero, or `array[i -1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: I’m not sure why this would apply only for negative numbers, but one issue is the bounds of the inner while loop. The line `while(array[i] < array[i - 1] && i >= 0)` will run the loop for `i == 0`, and that means `std::swap(array[i], array[i - 1])` will evaluate `array[-1]`, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielH: I think it's because only the one with negative numbers needs a swap. The one with positive numbers is already sorted, so it doesn't reach the problem code.

Comment: @FredLarson And the same error would show up for `std::vector<int> array = {2, 1}; insertionSort(array)`? That makes sense; I should have checked the test cases better.

Comment: You're building a trap for yourself by iterating over i in the for loop and then messing with i in the loop body.

Comment: @all - Thanks! My bad, should have seen that.